# Is it better to use jQuery fadeIn or CSS3 animations?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, fadein

I am creating a simple gallery using some PHP and JavaScript and am trying to do a fade transition between images. Then I wondered if there is a performance difference between using a CSS animation, e.g.:

```
@-webkit-keyframes fadeIn {
0%   { opacity: 0; }
100% { opacity: 1; }
}
```

and a jQuery fadeIn.

I would like to use the callback from the fadeIn but I also can just use a timer with the CSS I guess.

Are either of these likely to work better with large images? I can't see a difference, but wondered if it might affect slower computers.

Comment: For a better cross-browser compatibility, consider also using the unprefixed and `-moz-` etc. versions of this code.

Comment: of course, i just use webkit here to make the code shorter in the post. Thanks for the reminder though ;p

Comment: @mgraph - jQuery may support IE for fades, but a lot of the time it looks awful because no matter how good jQuery is, it can't hide the fundamental limitations of IE.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

How about one with a fallback to the other? Use CSS3 transitions where possible, and use a feature detection library such as Modernizr to determine if the user's browser is capable of CSS3 transitions.

If AND ONLY IF the user's browser does not support native animations, only then should you use jQuery.

Native animations are GPU accelerated, resulting in less constraint on the CPU, and much smoother animations. Also, IT DOESN'T REQUIRE JAVASCRIPT nor does it take extra requests to pull off.

Comment: If the browser doesn't support native animations then simply don't animate as they will look like crap :)

Comment: 4 answers and 3 of them less than -4?! I would say this was a **very** good question!

Comment: CSS3 looks like the right place for clean animations code but many statistics prove that you are sometimes wrong when it comes to performance.

Comment: @netAction I'm not familiar with a case where jQuery outperforms native CSS animations.

Answer (score 6):

Well, I think using CSS animation is a lot better when there is a supported browser and you should use jQuery only as a backup for unsupported browsers. As thoroughly explained on http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/css3-vs-jquery-animations, they conducted test of animating 300 divs at the same time with both CSS and jQuery, and noticed a huge difference between the performance statistics.

Statistics using **CSS** the animation were:

  - Number of actions performed to finish the animation: 100
  - Time taken to finish executing the animation: 2.9 seconds
  - Memory consumed at the end of the animation: 1.5 MB

and Statistics using **jQuery** were:

  - Number of actions performed to finish the animation: 2119
  - Time taken to finish executing the animation: 5 seconds
  - Memory consumed at the end of the animation: 6 MB

So, as you can see, there is a great difference between the performance. This is because the browser's CSS processor is written in C++ and native code executes very fast whereas jQuery (JavaScript) is an interpreted language and the browser can't predict JavaScript ahead in time very well, in terms of what event will occur next, which restricts browsers to optimize it for performance.
I hope that answers your question.