# Which is better: Jquery.animate() or css transitions with setTimeOut

Tags: javascript, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it better to use jQuery fadeIn or CSS3 animations?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10863000/is-it-better-to-use-jquery-fadein-or-css3-animations)
>   [what’s faster? CSS3 transitions or jQuery animations?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10984771/whats-faster-css3-transitions-or-jquery-animations)

I am trying to do an animation and speed is of an essence. I have tried two methods both of which work, however I would like to know which one is more effective.

Method 1: Using Jquery.animate()
My code looks something like:

```
$("div").animate({opacity: "show"}, 100, "linear", function() {
    console.log("Animation Complete");
});
```

Method 2: Using Css transitions with setTimeOut:
This is what the code looks like:

```
$("div").addClass("hidden") //On Page load
```

Then to animate the fade in:

```
setTimeout(function () {
    $("div").removeClass('hidden');
}, 100);
```

Hidden has the following style property:

```
.hidden { opacity: 0 !important; }
```

Both work rather well, but I want to know which one is more efficient/better.

Comment: The animate method is probably more maintainable (all of the code is in one place), however in low power environments (mobile/tablet) the transitions may provide better performance.

Comment: Don't use `!important`.  Make your selector stronger.

Comment: Unfortunately I couldnt add the answer myself as this question has been closed but upon deeper analysis the animate method is better. Why? Well to truly understand this we need to remember that Javascript runs on a single thread. When setTimeout is called, it blocks the thread for that duration, even if it is 100 ms, for efficiency every nano second is important. The animate method (upon inspection of the jquery source) is implemented through the use of a  "ticker", which is basically a counter that checks the difference between the datetime of when it was activated to the current one.

Comment: *Continuing from the above comment* Having a ticker implementation within the code makes the able to run asynchronously(this is how asynchronous ajax calls are implemented btw). Hence even though css transitions are rendered faster by the browser, the code itself is blocked in the setTimeOut block. Whereas in the animate implementation, there is no such blockin that occurs.

Comment: I disagree with you, @gilly3. The "hidden" class must be able to be placed on any element, which could have arbitrarily strong selectors already on it. While "!important" is usually a code smell, this is a correct use of the modifier.

Comment: I see your point, but I'm sticking to my guns.  If you need this to be portable, you can just do `$("div").css({ opacity: 0 })` which will work everywhere... unless some other class has used `!important`.

Answer (score 2):

Go with transitions unless the JavaScript animations offer you something that the transitions don't.

Transitions are implemented at browser level and in some cases are hardware accelerated, so they should typically be as fast as possible.

Moreover, the code is a lot simpler.

Answer (score 1):

Transitions perform much better because they are implemented natively in the browser and often use hardware acceleration.  See [this jQuery animate vs CSS transitions performance comparison demo](http://css3.bradshawenterprises.com/blog/jquery-vs-css3-transitions/) at [Rich Bradshaw](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16511/rich-bradshaw)'s blog.  Use transitions by default.  Only use jQuery as a fallback for older browsers if necessary.

[This article](http://blog.alexmaccaw.com/css-transitions) has a nice discussion of CSS transitions and performance including hardware acceleration.

Answer (score 0):

Animate is better for that.`setTimeout()` removes a css class immediately after some time, but `animate` gradually fades it in/out.

Answer (score 0):

using jquery animation will help you if your fade out time is more than 100ms..